# "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library" error

Tags: android, layout, styles, android-appcompat

I'm getting "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library" error every time even if I'm obviously using an AppCompat Theme (a descendant one).

**dependencies:**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
```

**layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tooltip_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tooltip_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_delete_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/tooltip_image"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**theme:**

```
<style name="TranslucentAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

**manifest:**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/TranslucentAppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            (...)
</activity>
```

I'm inflating the layout inside a **service**:

```
tooltipContainer = (CoordinatorLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tooltip_layout, null);
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Create a `ContextThemeWrapper` to wrap the `Service`'s `Context` with your custom theme, and get the `LayoutInflater` from that.

```java
ContextThemeWrapper ctx = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.TranslucentAppTheme);
tooltipContainer = (CoordinatorLayout) LayoutInflater.from(ctx)
    .inflate(R.layout.tooltip_layout, null);
```

[`ContextThemeWrapper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html) modifies the given `Context`'s theme with the one you specify in the constructor. Since a `Service` doesn't really have a theme, it just tacks yours onto the `Service`'s `Context`, then the `LayoutInflater` has the appropriate theme to inflate the library `View`s.

---

Alternatively, if handling it in the layout XML would be more appropriate or less involved, you might be able set an `android:theme` attribute on the root `<ViewGroup>`, which simply causes the `LayoutInflater` to do the `Context` wrapping internally. For example:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ...
    android:theme="@style/TranslucentAppTheme">
```

However, this will only work with the platform `LayoutInflater` starting with Lollipop (API level 21). The support/androidx libraries are able to handle that attribute on older versions, but the way it's set up is intended for use in `Activity` classes only, and it's likely simpler to just do the wrapping yourself in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I think Mike M solution is the right one if you're getting the error from a service, which is how the original question is stated.  I think Yevhen is talking about getting this problem that is not originating from a service. It's to that case which, which I'll share my solution.

I was getting the same error stating that I needed to use a Theme.AppCompat theme.  In my case it was from a custom dialog that contained 6 NumberPicker widgets.  That error would occur 6 times (one for each widget) whenever I opened that dialog. Here's what my styles orginally looked like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And, this is what I did to correct the problem:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Notice that I didn't have AppTheme.NoActionBar deriving from an Theme.AppCompat theme.

Answer (score -2):

Also receive such error in logcat:

> "E/ThemeUtils: View class
> TableCircleCustomView is
> an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme
> (or descendant)."

My app theme is "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Here is my custom view class:

```
class TableCircleCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AppCompatTextView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    ....
}
```

Then in Fragment i'm adding this object to RelativeLayout like so

```
val viewItem = TableCircleCustomView(context)     
with(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(objectWidth, objectHeight)) {
  leftMargin = objectPosX
  topMargin = objectPosY
    
  binding.restaurantMap.addView(viewItem, this);
}
```

Can somebody help to solve it. Have no idea for what element i should set theme and how ((

Comment: Post a new question, not an answer which is a question ;-)