# Cannot show TabLayout in InputView

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout, android-input-method

I'm creating an Android input method, and want to use `TabLayout` from the support library in the `InputView` (the UI where the user inputs text in the form of keyclicks).

The layout for the `InputView` is very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<org.szm.enigma2.ime.InputView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                               android:orientation="vertical"
                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout android:id="@+id/tab"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                             style="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem android:text="Hello"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem android:text="World"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem android:text="Enigma"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</org.szm.enigma2.ime.InputView>
```

And I use the same layout for both `InputView` and the settings activity, which is a normal activity.

Create `InputView` from subclass of `InputMethodService`:

```
return getLayoutInflator().inflat(R.layout.input_view, null);
```

Inside the constructor of settings activity class:

```
setContentView(R.layout.input_view);
```

When I run the program, the settings activity is normal. Then tab layout is working perfectly. But when I activate the input method's input view, the program crashes with the following info:

```
09-08 18:56:49.064 28437-28437/org.szm.enigma2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: org.szm.enigma2, PID: 28437
        android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:812)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
            at org.szm.enigma2.ime.InputService.onCreateInputView(InputService.java:42)
            at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.updateInputViewShown(InputMethodService.java:1228)
            at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.showWindowInner(InputMethodService.java:1622)
            at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.showWindow(InputMethodService.java:1590)
            at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService$InputMethodImpl.showSoftInput(InputMethodService.java:442)
            at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.executeMessage(IInputMethodWrapper.java:206)
            at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:37)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6175)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
            at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:33)
            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.<init>(TabLayout.java:297)
            at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.<init>(TabLayout.java:291)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:812) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:752) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
            at org.szm.enigma2.ime.InputService.onCreateInputView(InputService.java:42) 
            at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.updateInputViewShown(InputMethodService.java:1228) 
            at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.showWindowInner(InputMethodService.java:1622) 
            at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.showWindow(InputMethodService.java:1590) 
            at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService$InputMethodImpl.showSoftInput(InputMethodService.java:442) 
            at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.executeMessage(IInputMethodWrapper.java:206) 
            at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:37) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6175) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764) 
09-08 18:56:49.081 28437-28437/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28437 SIG: 9
```

I don't know why it didn't work even if I set the `style` attribute. And how can I use tab layout in an input view? (since input view is not inside any activity)

Thanks

#### EDIT

I have already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712563/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-tablayout) and googled other resources. Most of them is dealing with error of inflating TabLayout in Activity. My problem is that TabLayout works **fine** inside Activity but not in input view.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%236%3A+Error+inflating+class+android.support.design.widget.TabLayout&oq=%236%3A+Error+inflating+class+android.support.design.widget.TabLayout&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924481/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-the-design-library

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_NoActionBar);
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.XXXXX, null);
```

the Tablayout is in the R.layout.XXXXX