# Error inflating TabLayout on Jelly Bean and KitKat

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have the following TabLayout in my activity which works fine on Nougat, Marshmallow, and Lollipop, but throws an exception on Jelly Bean and KitKat. Any ideas? This has become beyond frustrating.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        p1:minWidth="25px"
        p1:minHeight="25px"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:id="@+id/notificationTypes"
        p1:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

    Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TabLayout ---> Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException' was thrown. ---> Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
```

Comment: the solution was already mentioned in the stack `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library. `

Comment: IIRC, the `theme` attribute for individual `View`s wasn't introduced until Lollipop. Is there a reason you're not using an `AppCompat` theme for the whole `Activity`?

Comment: I think that's the problem, versions earlier than Lollipop are simply not recognizing the theme attribute on the TabLayout, never mind what it's set to, leaving me to set the theme on the activity level.  My problem with this is that the way my app is structured with base classes, I would need to switch the entire app over to AppCompat.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: I'm not sure what your perceived problem is with the base classes, but I would mention that you can set the theme per `<activity>`. If you don't want to do that, for whatever reason, you could inflate the `TabLayout`/whole layout manually with an inflater from a `ContextThemeWrapper` on an `AppCompat` theme, like is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36924702.