# How to use AppCompatCheckBox inside InputMethodService?

Tags: android, checkbox, keyboard, android-appcompat

I am creating a custom keyboard with InputMethodService, there are checkboxes inside my keyboard and i need to change the color. I've found that you can use this for min API 21+

```
<Checkbox
  android:buttonTint="@color/red" />
```

and with AppCompat

```
<Checkbox
  app:buttonTint="@color/red" />
```

but when i run my keyboard, the color does not change at all

is it because im not running on a `AppCompatActivity`?

Edit: Screenshot of my checkbox
[image]

Comment: can you provide more details like screen shot of soft keyboard with selected and un-selected checkbox

Comment: Hi @alokHarman i have added the screenshot, it's still using the default color

Comment: "is it because im not running on a `AppCompatActivity`?" – Basically, yes. You'll need to do two things to replace that functionality in a `Service`. First. use the fully-qualified class name in the XML tag – e.g., `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox>`. Secondly, you'll need to wrap the `Service` `Context` in a `ContextThemeWrapper` with an appropriate theme, and obtain the `LayoutInflater` from that, like is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36924702).

Comment: You're right @MikeM. Thanks a lot, how can i mark your comment as the answer to my question ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment earlier. Thanks for getting an answer posted. Please make sure to accept it in a couple of days, when the system lets you, so that your question will show as resolved. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Mike M. said in the comments, i need to use `ContextThemeWrapper`. This is how i do it

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctx = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.AppTheme);
inflate(ctx, R.layout.my_layout, view);
```