# View class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant)

Tags: android, android-appcompat

`View class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).`

Got this message in Logcat after upgrading to `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0`

I don't use styles.
Why do I get it?

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:maxWidth="80dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:lines="2"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"/>
```

Also, this TextView is not part of an Activity, but added to the WindowManager from a Service

Comment: Check your manifest and your styles.xml file to know your app theme

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti It's `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36924702.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM. That was it! I'll accept the answer if you want to post it here.