# android inflate view with app theme from service

Tags: java, android, xml

Basically, I have an application and I would like to overlay fab button on any application and home screen, for that I used service class with custom layout with fab button. But app getting crash with error

```
 Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
```

When I adding theme to the view i am getting crash again with error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Java

```
  @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
     customView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_head_service, null);
}
```

xml

```
<com.imangazaliev.circlemenu.CircleMenu
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:buttonColors="@array/fab_menu_colors"
        app:buttonIcons="@array/fab_menu_icons"
        app:distance="120dp"
        app:centerButtonIconColor="#ffffff"
        app:maxAngle="140"
        app:menuIcon="plus"
        app:showSelectAnimation="false"/>
```

Exception Stacktrace

```
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.imangazaliev.circlemenu.CircleMenu
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.imangazaliev.circlemenu.CircleMenu
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
            at CustomFloatingViewService.onStartCommand(CustomFloatingViewService.java:92)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3668)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:200)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1682)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
            at com.imangazaliev.circlemenu.CircleMenu.initMenuLayout(CircleMenu.kt:108)
            at com.imangazaliev.circlemenu.CircleMenu.<init>(CircleMenu.kt:87)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
            at CustomFloatingViewService.onStartCommand(CustomFloatingViewService.java:92) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3668) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:200) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1682) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36924481/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-the-design-library/36924702#36924702

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I tried this solution but getting error. java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Comment: Can you post more of the exception stack trace? It looks like some widget misbehaves because it assumes it's always inflated inside activity and doesn't account for context wrappers

Comment: @Pawel Please check updated question.

Comment: You're using custom view which [performs a crude cast of context to activity](https://github.com/ImangazalievM/CircleMenu/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/imangazaliev/circlemenu/CircleMenu.kt#L108). We won't be able to help you here, if you care enough you should open an issue on projects github.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **getApplicationContext()**

customView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_head_service, null);